# Should my IoT hub be in a private vnet? And if so how do I implement it into my infrastructure?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-virtual-network

I have Raspberry Pi which sends data to my IoT hub, which will then use an azure stream analytics job to send data to the SQL database, and finally the data will be used by my app service to visualize the data. I have heard that I should implement private endpoints/private vnet for my IoT hub for security enhancement. However, how will my Raspberry Pi send data to the IoT Hub? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

IoT Hub can connect to your Azure blob storage, event hub, service bus resources for message routing, file upload, and bulk device import/export over the resources' public endpoint. Binding your IoT Hub resource to a VNet blocks connectivity to the resource by default. As a result, this configuration prevents IoT hubs from sending data to your resources. To fix this issue, enable connectivity from your IoT Hub resource to your storage account, event hub, or service bus resources via the trusted Microsoft service option.

To allow other services to find your IoT hub as a trusted Microsoft service, your hub must use a managed identity. Once a managed identity is provisioned, grant permission to your hub's managed identity to access your custom endpoint. Follow the article [Managed identities support in IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-managed-identity) to provision a managed identity with Azure role-based access control (RBAC) permission, and add the custom endpoint to your IoT hub. Make sure you turn on the trusted Microsoft first party exception to allow your IoT hubs access to the custom endpoint if you have the firewall configurations in place.

Please refer the resource [IoT Hub support for virtual networks with Azure Private Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/virtual-network-support) to have a better understanding on this issue.